# What did Donald Trump mean when he said "Baldwin impersonation"?

Tags: meaning

> Just tried watching Saturday Night Live - unwatchable! Totally biased, not funny and the Baldwin impersonation just can't get any worse. Sad
>
> https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/805278955150471168

Definition of impersonation -

> an act of pretending to be another person for the purpose of entertainment or fraud.

How does that relate to a tv show on CNN? What is the meaning of impersonation in this context?

Comment: [Saturday Night Live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturday_Night_Live) is an American late-night live television sketch comedy and variety show, not a political show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Saturday Night Live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturday_Night_Live) is an American late-night live television sketch comedy and variety show, not a political show.

You have the correct definition of impersonation. Actor Alec Baldwin does an impersonation of Donald Trump on the show for entertainment. Here is one [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUWSLlz0Fdo). For reference, here is an image.

[image: Donald Trump]

([The Hollywood Reporter](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/alec-baldwin-donald-trump-impression-debate-934213))

By "Baldwin impersonation", Trump means "the impersonation of me done by Baldwin".

You might have thought it meant that Baldwin was the one being impersonated, but that doesn't make sense given the context.